# receiving file in node-express uploaded with xhr

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I have a xmlhttprequest which uploads the file and I am trying to receive it in my node-express server. but for some reason I am not able to retrieve the file content in the server. Not sure where I am missing it.

```
app.post('/api/uploadfiles', function(req, res) {
   console.log("apicalled");
   console.log(req);
   console.log(req.body);
   console.log(req.files);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(req.files));
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for you to see the files, you will need to add another middleware that parses multi-part request.
Try using connect-multiparty module like so:

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty'); //for files upload
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();//for files upload

app.post('/api/uploadfiles', multipartMiddleware, function(req, res) {
   console.log("apicalled");
   console.log(req);
   console.log(req.body);
   console.log(req.files);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(req.files));
});
```