# Angular 6 and Node Js AWS S3 File Upload Progress Bar

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a progress bar when uploading files via Angular 6 (frontend) and NodeJs (backend) to an asw-s3 bucket.
How to fetch the progress (or the already uploaded bytes) and receive them in the Angular 6 frontend in realtime?

Comment: What code have you attempted this with? Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if angular has a specific method for this, but here is a working example I used in some of my angular based websites :

```
sendFile(file) {
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('my_file', file);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (progEvent: ProgressEvent) {
        if (progEvent.lengthComputable) {
            var uploadedSoFar = (progEvent.loaded / progEvent.total) * 100;
            console.log("Uploaded: " + uploadedSoFar + "% ")
            if (progEvent.loaded == progEvent.total){
                // uploaded up to 100%
            }
        }

    };
    xhr.open("POST", `/your_site`, true);
    xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Some explanation of what is going on :

**FormData**

> The FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of
>   key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can
>   then be easily sent using the XMLHttpRequest.send() method. It uses
>   the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to
>   "multipart/form-data"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

**XMLHttpRequest**

> Use XMLHttpRequest (XHR) objects to interact with servers. You can
>   retrieve data from a URL without having to do a full page refresh.
>   This enables a Web page to update just part of a page without
>   disrupting what the user is doing.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

**Node Side**
I'm updating this post to add a node code sample (after the comments). I am not as good in node.js, so my following code is not a good example.

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  // Remove this, I use it for this example to be easy to reproduce
  res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOWALL');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  if (req.method == 'POST') {
        console.log("Receiving file");
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
            console.log("receiving data : " + body);
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            console.log("received all the data: " + body);
        });
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end('Reception completed');
    }

});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

If you receive data in your node.js, this would mean that your front is working correctly.

Comment: This really helps! But how would you extract the file from the formData in the backend?

Comment: Depends on your backend. in django, you can extract the file from the request : 
`my_file = request.FILES['my_file']`. 
If you want to store it, if you're in python backend : `fs = FileSystemStorage(); fs.save(filename, my_file)`

Comment: I am getting an `undefined` when accessing `req.FILES['file']`

Comment: What is your backend ?

Comment: I am using NodeJs

Comment: maybe try to `console.log( req.files)`. 
here's a post that gives more details on receiving a file through xhr on node.js :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669500/receiving-file-in-node-express-uploaded-with-xhr

Comment: I have added the `multipartMiddleware` but `req.files` does return an empty object `{}`, also `req.files['file']` is again `undefined`

Comment: I updated my answer, please tell me if it fixes your problem

Comment: The post route executes, but the `req.on('data')` isn't called.

Comment: I managed to fetch the file data via `busboy`, and the upload to the s3 bucket works, too. But the progress is instantly at 100% even if the file upload finished many seconds later.

Comment: I edited my post to make it more compatible, and tested it. Please try it in this format and tell me if this works. 
One other explanation could be that the file you are transferring is too small, in this case try with a "slow 3g connection". You have this option in chrome performance toolbox.

Comment: `uploadedSoFar` is still 100% instantly and I am not able to find the setting for another connection http://prntscr.com/k2vtm3

Comment: I may have found the issue... The problem might occur because I am hosting the server locally... I will notify you in a few minutes

Comment: The progress percentage works fine when running the server not locally.

Comment: But I still have one problem... the percentage is correctly logged but does not update on the page: `xhr.upload.onprogress = (progEvent: ProgressEvent) => {
      if (progEvent.lengthComputable) {
        this.uploadedPercentage = (progEvent.loaded / progEvent.total) * 100; // uploadedPercentage does not update in the html
        console.log(this.uploadedPercentage + '%'); // this log is outputted correctly
        if (progEvent.loaded == progEvent.total) {
          this.uploadedPercentage = 100;
        }
      }` I use the progress in the html like: `{{uploadedPercentage}}`

Comment: I can't think of a reason other than "the transfer is really fast, faster than changeDetection refreshing time.". But this is a bit detached from the transfer problem per say. 
What I can advise is to read this post about "triggering detection changes": 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-change-detection-manually-in-angular
Good luck ;) !

Comment: okay, I will try it... something interesting to note is, that the progress updates when I am clicking somewhere on the page

Comment: I believe that detection change fires when an event occurs. You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 2):

you can just upload a file with the regular HttpClient and use the flag `reportProgress: true`.

Full example:

```
constructor(private _http: HttpClient,
            private _logger: Logger) {}

this._http
    .post(FILE_UPLOAD_URL, formData, {
          reportProgress: true,
          observe: 'events'
        })
        .subscribe((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            switch (event.type) {
                case HttpEventType.Sent:
                    this._logger.debug('Upload started');
                    break;
                case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
                    // Live stats are also possible for downloads
                case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
                    if (event.total) {
                         const progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                         const timeElapsed = Date.now() - startTime;
                         const uploadSpeed = event.loaded / (timeElapsed / 1000);
                         const uploadTimeRemaining = Math.ceil(
                                            (event.total - event.loaded) / uploadSpeed
                                        );
                         const uploadTimeElapsed = Math.ceil(timeElapsed / 1000);
                         const uploadSpeed = uploadSpeed / 1024 / 1024;
                         this._logger.debug('Upload stats:', progress, timeElapsed, uploadSpeed, uploadTimeRemaining,  uploadTimeElapsed, uploadSpeed);

                         break;
                     case HttpEventType.Response:
                          this.progressForFile = 100;
                          this._logger.debug('Done! ResponseBody:', event.body);

                 });
```

If hope, this helps! :-)

Comment: This really helped! Unfortunately, the progress does not track the upload progress. It's almost instantly 100% and the upload finishes seconds later.