# angular rxjs : report progress of upload on chained observable events?

Tags: angular, file-upload, rxjs

When we want to report upload progress of a http request we add options to the request.

I.e.

```
const url = environment.content_creator_self_content_feed_posts_get + '/' + 
 this.createdpost.id;
          this.http.put(url, payload, {
            reportProgress: true,
            observe: 'events'
          }).subscribe(
              (event: any)=>{
                switch (event.type){
                  case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
                    this.coverphotoprogress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                    break;
                  case HttpEventType.Response:

                }

              });
```

but how do we do the same when we are chaining observables?

example take this request:

```
uploadmedia(event, type){

    this.s3.privateresourceuploadtos3(event, this.createdpost.contentcreator, this.createdpost.id, type)
      .subscribe(
        (req: any)=> {
          this.mediahasbeenuploaded = true;

        });
  }
```

and then the `privateresourceuploadtos3` function it is subscribing to

```
privateresourceuploadtos3(event, userid, contentpostid, contenttype): Observable<any>{

    const mediatobeuploaded = event.target.files[0];
    const url = environment.private_generate_presigned_url_resource + userid + '/' + contentpostid + '/' + contenttype;
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      switchMap((req : any)=>{
        const resourceurl = req.uriroot + req.fields.key;

        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('acl', req.fields.acl);
        fd.append('key', req.fields.key);
        fd.append('content-type', req.fields['content-type']);
        fd.append('policy', req.fields.policy);
        fd.append('x-amz-meta-user', req.fields['x-amz-meta-user']);
        fd.append('x-amz-meta-contentpost', req.fields['x-amz-meta-contentpost']);
        fd.append('x-amz-meta-rawbucketkey', req.fields['x-amz-meta-rawbucketkey']);
        fd.append('x-amz-algorithm', req.fields['x-amz-algorithm']);
        fd.append('x-amz-credential', req.fields['x-amz-credential']);
        fd.append('x-amz-date', req.fields['x-amz-date']);
        fd.append('x-amz-signature', req.fields['x-amz-signature']);
        fd.append('file', mediatobeuploaded);
        return this.http.post(req.url, fd).pipe(
          // answer two https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176537/angular-6-and-node-js-aws-s3-file-upload-progress-bar

          switchMap((req2: any)=>{
            const result = {
              resourceurl : resourceurl,
              resourcekey: req.fields.key
            };
            return of(result);
          }));
      }));
  }
```

this part in particular

```
return this.http.post(req.url, fd).pipe(
              switchMap((req2: any)=>{
                const result = {
                  resourceurl : resourceurl,
                  resourcekey: req.fields.key
                };
                return of(result);
              }));
          }));
```

the request is made then we use `switchMap` to change to another observable which returns an object of the request.

it would make sense that the options be added to this http request. Something like

```
return this.http.post(req.url, fd, {
                reportProgress: true,
                observe: 'events'
                 }).pipe(
                  switchMap((req2: any)=>{
                    const result = {
                      resourceurl : resourceurl,
                      resourcekey: req.fields.key
                    };
                    return of(result);
                  }));
              }));
```

but im not exactly sure to what I would do next so that one if the request is done it returns the result.

or if not. It returns a event and the code that is subscribe to the function listening to `privateresourceuploadtos3` is receciving the progress events so that can be displayed on the screen

```
uploadmedia(event, type){
    
        this.s3.privateresourceuploadtos3(event, this.createdpost.contentcreator, this.createdpost.id, type)
          .subscribe(
            (req: any)=> {
              this.mediahasbeenuploaded = true;
    
            });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

this was my hacky solution. But I guess it works. But I always remember. If it's stupid but it works it isn't stupid. And a CPU is a rock we tricked into thinking.

```
privateresourceuploadtos3(event, userid, contentpostid, contenttype): Observable<any>{

    const mediatobeuploaded = event.target.files[0];
    const url = environment.private_generate_presigned_url_resource + userid + '/' + contentpostid + '/' + contenttype;
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      switchMap((req : any)=>{
        const resourceurl = req.uriroot + req.fields.key;

        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('acl', req.fields.acl);
        fd.append('key', req.fields.key);
        fd.append('content-type', req.fields['content-type']);
        fd.append('policy', req.fields.policy);
        fd.append('x-amz-meta-user', req.fields['x-amz-meta-user']);
        fd.append('x-amz-meta-contentpost', req.fields['x-amz-meta-contentpost']);
        fd.append('x-amz-meta-rawbucketkey', req.fields['x-amz-meta-rawbucketkey']);
        fd.append('x-amz-algorithm', req.fields['x-amz-algorithm']);
        fd.append('x-amz-credential', req.fields['x-amz-credential']);
        fd.append('x-amz-date', req.fields['x-amz-date']);
        fd.append('x-amz-signature', req.fields['x-amz-signature']);
        fd.append('file', mediatobeuploaded);
        return this.http.post(req.url, fd, {
          reportProgress: true,
          observe: 'events'
        }).pipe(
          // answer two https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176537/angular-6-and-node-js-aws-s3-file-upload-progress-bar

          switchMap((event: any)=>{
            switch(event.type){
              case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
                const result = {
                  progressreport: true,
                  progress: Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100)
                  };
                return of(result);
              case HttpEventType.Response:
                const result = {
                  progressreport: false,
                  resourceurl : resourceurl,
                  resourcekey: req.fields.key
                };
                return of(result);
            }
          }));
      }));
  }
```