# switchmap complains not returning but thought i was

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, switchmap

here is the error:

`ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

Here is the code

```
publicresourceuploadtos3(event): Observable<any>{
    console.log('it got inside the public resource upload to s3 ');
    const mediatobeuploaded = event.target.files[0];
    return this.http.get(environment.public_generate_presigned_url_resource).pipe(
      switchMap((req : any)=>{
        const resourceurlprovided = req.uriroot + req.fields.key;
        console.log('it got the public presigned url');

        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('acl', req.fields.acl);
        fd.append('key', req.fields.key);
        fd.append('content-type', req.fields['content-type']);
        fd.append('policy', req.fields.policy);
        fd.append('x-amz-algorithm', req.fields['x-amz-algorithm']);
        fd.append('x-amz-credential', req.fields['x-amz-credential']);
        fd.append('x-amz-date', req.fields['x-amz-date']);
        fd.append('x-amz-signature', req.fields['x-amz-signature']);

        fd.append('file', mediatobeuploaded);
        return this.http.post(req.url, fd, {
         reportProgress: true,
         observe: 'events'
       }).pipe(
         // answer two https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176537/angular-6-and-node-js-aws-s3-file-upload-progress-bar
         switchMap((events: any)=>{
           console.log('it got into the swtich map');
           switch(events.type){
             case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
               const result = {
                 progressreport: true,
                 progress: Math.round(events.loaded / events.total * 100)
               };
               console.log('it went into upload progress');
               return of(result);
             case HttpEventType.Response:
               const result2 = {
                 progressreport: false,
                 resourceurl: resourceurlprovided,
                 resourcekey: req.fields.key
               };
               console.log('it went into the response');
               return of(result2);
           }
         }));

      }));
  }
```

notice the `console.log()` statements. The last one to fire is `console.log('it got into the switch map')`

which means my switch map is calling this error because it expects to return observables.

but look at this code.

```
switch(events.type){
             case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
               const result = {
                 progressreport: true,
                 progress: Math.round(events.loaded / events.total * 100)
               };
               console.log('it went into upload progress');
               return of(result);
             case HttpEventType.Response:
               const result2 = {
                 progressreport: false,
                 resourceurl: resourceurlprovided,
                 resourcekey: req.fields.key
               };
               console.log('it went into the response');
               return of(result2);
           }
         }));
```

what of the `return of` statements why don't those satisfy? What am i doing wrong? My understanding is that the return of is an observable.

Part of my thought process is that I need to have a default of statment if the two switch case statements don't work. But I tried that and my IDE kept yelling at me. So either Im doing something completely silly, or I am missing something important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're returning `of(result)` inside a `switchMap()`, then use `map()` instead. You can simply return the result without wrapping it in `of()`.
2. Your switch block handles two cases, but what if both cases fail? That is when you are not returning anything. Try adding a default case at the end to return something if both cases fail.